"Custom product cannot be added to the cart Woocommerce, why?"
"I've created my first custom product with its 'variants', meant to have divisions based on dimensions and prices. Generally, everything works fine in the admin panel, but unfortunately, when I tried to add a product, for example with ID 47156 and its variant ID 6627db9886b28, I get the following message in the browser console:
Product ID: 47156
roleta-1/:340 Variant ID: 6627db9886b28
roleta-1/:341 Nonce: f02f367310
roleta-1/:353 AJAX Response: {success: false, data: {…}}"
This is the code that creates a custom product in woocommerce:
// Register custom product type
function register_custom_product_type() {
    class WC_Product_Custom_Roll_Dimensions extends WC_Product {
        public $product_type;

        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'custom_roll_dimensions';
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }
    }

    // Add the custom product type to WooCommerce
    add_filter('product_type_selector', function( $types ){
        $types['custom_roll_dimensions'] = 'Wymiary Rolet';
        return $types;
    });
}
add_action('init', 'register_custom_product_type');

// Custom Variants Manager Class
class CustomVariantsManager {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueueStyles'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_and_localize_scripts'));
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'addCustomVariantsMetabox'));
        add_action('save_post', array($this, 'saveCustomVariants'), 10, 2);
        add_action('wp_ajax_custom_variants_pagination', array($this, 'customVariantsPagination'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_variants_pagination', array($this, 'customVariantsPagination'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_remove_custom_variant', array($this, 'removeCustomVariantCallback'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_add_custom_variant', array($this, 'addCustomVariantCallback'));

        // Include the kalkulator.php file
        include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'Kalkulator.php');
    }

    // Enqueue styles for the admin area
    public function enqueueStyles() {
        wp_enqueue_style('moj-wtyczka-styl', plugins_url('css/moj-wtyczka-styl.css', __FILE__));
    }
    
    // Enqueue and localize scripts for admin area
    public function enqueue_and_localize_scripts(){
        // Enqueue your JavaScript file
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-variants-scripts', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'JS/custom-variants-scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

        // Localize the script with necessary data
        wp_localize_script('custom-variants-scripts', 'ajax_object', array(
            'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), // Make sure this points to admin-ajax.php
        ));
        wp_localize_script('custom-variants-scripts', 'custom_script_vars', array(
            'post_id' => get_the_ID(), // Notice the comma here
        ));
    }

    // Add the custom variants metabox
    public function addCustomVariantsMetabox() {
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_variants_metabox_id',   // Unique ID
            'Warianty Produktu',            // Box title
            array($this, 'customVariantsMetaboxHtml'), // Content callback, must be of type callable
            ['product', 'custom_roll_dimensions'], // Support for new product type
            'normal'
        );
    }

    // Metabox HTML
    public function customVariantsMetaboxHtml($post) {
        wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'custom_variants_nonce');
        $variants = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_variants', true);
        if (!is_array($variants)) {
            $variants = [];
        }
        $shipping_classes = get_terms('product_shipping_class', array('hide_empty' => false));

        echo '<div id="custom_variants_containers">';
        echo '<button id="add_variant" type="button">Dodaj Nowy Wariant</button>';
        echo '<button id="remove_all_variants" type="button">Usuń Wszystkie Warianty</button>';
        $totalVariants = count($variants);
        echo '<div id="total_variants">Wszystkie: ' . $totalVariants . '</div>';
        echo '<div id="custom_variants_container">';
        if ($variants) {
            foreach ($variants as $index => $variant) {
                echo '<div class="variant">';
                $dimensions = esc_attr($variant['width']) . 'x' . esc_attr($variant['height']);
                echo '<div id="variant_dimensionsss">';
                echo '<div id="variant_dimensionss" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">';
                echo '<span>ID wariantu: ' . esc_html($variant['id']) . '</span>';
                echo '<div id="variant_dimensions_' . $index . '" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-left:10px">';
                echo '<label for="variant_dimensions_' . $index . '">Wymiary:</label>';
                echo '<span id="variant_dimensions_' . $index . '">' . $dimensions . '</span>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<button class="remove_variant" type="button" data-index="' . $index . '">Usuń Wariant</button>';
                echo '<button class="rozwin_variant" type="button" data-index="' . $index . '">Rozwiń</button>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div id="custom_variants_containerx">';
                echo '<div id="custom_variants_container1" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); gap: 20px;">';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<label for="variant_width_' . $index . '">Szerokość</label>';
                echo '<input type="text" id="variant_width_' . $index . '" name="variants[' . $index . '][width]" value="' . esc_attr($variant['width']) . '" />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<label for="variant_height_' . $index . '">Wysokość</label>';
                echo '<input type="text" id="variant_height_' . $index . '" name="variants[' . $index . '][height]" value="' . esc_attr($variant['height']) . '" />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<label for="variant_sku_' . $index . '">SKU</label>';
                echo '<input type="text" id="variant_sku_' . $index . '" name="variants[' . $index . '][sku]" value="' . esc_attr($variant['sku']) . '" />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div id="custom_variants_container2" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); gap: 20px;">';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<label for="variant_regular_price_' . $index . '">Cena Regularna</label>';
                echo '<input type="text" id="variant_regular_price_' . $index . '" name="variants[' . $index . '][regular_price]" value="' . esc_attr($variant['regular_price']) . '" size="50" />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<label for="variant_sale_price_' . $index . '">Cena Promocyjna</label>';
                echo '<input type="text" id="variant_sale_price_' . $index . '" name="variants[' . $index . '][sale_price]" value="' . esc_attr($variant['sale_price']) . '" size="50" />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div id="custom_variants_container3" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); gap: 0px;">';
                echo '<label for="variant_weight_' . $index . '">Waga</label>';
                echo '<input type="text" id="variant_weight_' . $index . '" name="variants[' . $index . '][weight]" value="' . esc_attr($variant['weight']) . '" size="25" />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<label for="variant_stock_status_' . $index . '">Stan magazynowy:</label>';
                echo '<select id="variant_stock_status_' . $index . '" name="variants[' . $index . '][stock_status]">';
                echo '<option value="instock"' . (isset($variant['stock_status']) && $variant['stock_status'] === 'instock' ? ' selected' : '') . '>Na stanie</option>';
                echo '<option value="outofstock"' . (isset($variant['stock_status']) && $variant['stock_status'] === 'outofstock' ? ' selected' : '') . '>Brak na stanie</option>';
                echo '</select>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div id="custom_variants_container4" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); gap: px;">';
                echo '<label for="variant_shipping_class_' . $index . '">Klasa Wysyłkowa</label>';
                echo '<select name="variants[' . $index . '][shipping_class]" id="variant_shipping_class_' . $index . '" class="postform">';
                echo '<option value="-1"' . (!isset($variant['shipping_class']) || $variant['shipping_class'] == '-1' ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>Taka sama jak nadrzędny</option>';
                foreach ($shipping_classes as $class) {
                    $selected = (isset($variant['shipping_class']) && $variant['shipping_class'] == $class->slug) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($class->slug) . '"' . $selected . '>' . esc_html($class->name) . '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    // Save custom variants
    public function saveCustomVariants($post_id, $post) {
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return;
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['custom_variants_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_variants_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return;
        }
        if ($post->post_type != 'product' && $post->post_type != 'custom_roll_dimensions') {
            return;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['variants']) && is_array($_POST['variants'])) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_variants', $_POST['variants']);
        } else {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_variants');
        }
    }

    // Pagination AJAX handler
    public function customVariantsPagination() {
        $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
        $per_page = isset($_POST['per_page']) ? intval($_POST['per_page']) : 10;
        $post_id = isset($_POST['post_id']) ? intval($_POST['post_id']) : 0;

        $variants = get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_variants', true);
        if (!is_array($variants)) {
            $variants = [];
        }

        $total_variants = count($variants);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_variants / $per_page);

        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page;
        $paged_variants = array_slice($variants, $start, $per_page);

        ob_start();
        foreach ($paged_variants as $index => $variant) {
            echo '<div class="variant">';
            echo '<span>ID wariantu: ' . esc_html($variant['id']) . '</span>';
            echo '<span>Wymiary: ' . esc_html($variant['width']) . 'x' . esc_html($variant['height']) . '</span>';
            echo '<button class="remove_variant" type="button" data-index="' . $index . '">Usuń Wariant</button>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        $content = ob_get_clean();

        wp_send_json_success(array(
            'content' => $content,
            'total_pages' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }

    // Remove custom variant AJAX handler
    public function removeCustomVariantCallback() {
        if (!isset($_POST['post_id']) || !isset($_POST['index'])) {
            wp_send_json_error();
            return;
        }

        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
        $index = intval($_POST['index']);

        $variants = get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_variants', true);
        if (!is_array($variants)) {
            wp_send_json_error();
            return;
        }

        if ($index < 0 || $index >= count($variants)) {
            wp_send_json_error();
            return;
        }

        array_splice($variants, $index, 1);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_variants', $variants);

        wp_send_json_success();
    }

    // Add custom variant AJAX handler
    public function addCustomVariantCallback() {
        if (!isset($_POST['post_id']) || !isset($_POST['variant'])) {
            wp_send_json_error();
            return;
        }

        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
        $new_variant = $_POST['variant'];

        $variants = get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_variants', true);
        if (!is_array($variants)) {
            $variants = [];
        }

        $variants[] = $new_variant;
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_variants', $variants);

        wp_send_json_success();
    }
}

// Initialize the CustomVariantsManager class
new CustomVariantsManager();


I tried to add the code that will add a specific product from the created product and its variant, but unfortunately I keep getting an error
code for adding a specific product to the cart
function add_custom_variant_to_cart() {
    // Check nonce for security
    if (!check_ajax_referer('add_custom_variant_nonce', 'security', false)) {
        error_log('Nonce verification failed.');
        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Nonce verification failed.'));
        wp_die();
    }

    // Get the product ID and variant ID from the request
    $product_id = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? intval($_POST['product_id']) : 0;
    $variant_id = isset($_POST['variant_id']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['variant_id']) : '';

    error_log('Product ID: ' . $product_id);
    error_log('Variant ID: ' . $variant_id);

    // Check if the product ID and variant ID are valid
    if ($product_id && $variant_id) {
        $variants = get_post_meta($product_id, 'custom_variants', true);
        error_log('Variants: ' . print_r($variants, true));

        if (is_array($variants)) {
            foreach ($variants as $variant) {
                error_log('Checking variant: ' . print_r($variant, true));
                if ($variant['id'] === $variant_id) {
                    // Add to cart
                    $cart_item_data = array(
                        'variant_id' => $variant_id,
                        'custom_variant_data' => $variant,
                    );
                    $added = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1, 0, array(), $cart_item_data);
                    error_log('Add to cart result: ' . print_r($added, true));

                    if ($added) {
                        wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Product added to cart'));
                    } else {
                        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Failed to add product to cart'));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            error_log('No valid variants found.');
        }
    } else {
        error_log('Invalid product ID or variant ID.');
    }

    wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Unable to add product to cart'));
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_add_custom_variant_to_cart', 'add_custom_variant_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_custom_variant_to_cart', 'add_custom_variant_to_cart');





// Example JavaScript to handle AJAX request
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_add_to_cart_script');
function custom_add_to_cart_script() {
    ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#custom_add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var product_id = 47156;
        var variant_id = '6627db9886b28';
        var security = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('add_custom_variant_nonce'); ?>';

        console.log('Product ID:', product_id);
        console.log('Variant ID:', variant_id);
        console.log('Nonce:', security);

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'add_custom_variant_to_cart',
                product_id: product_id,
                variant_id: variant_id,
                security: security
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('AJAX Response:', response);
                if (response.success) {
                    alert(response.data.message);
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>';
                } else {
                    alert(response.data.message);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('AJAX Error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
                console.log('Response Text:', jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>


    <?php
}

// Filter to add custom data to cart item
function custom_add_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['custom_variant_data'])) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_variant_data'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_variant_data']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'custom_add_cart_item_data', 10, 3);

// Display custom variant data in the cart
function custom_get_item_data($item_data, $cart_item) {
    if (isset($cart_item['custom_variant_data'])) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __('Variant Dimensions', 'textdomain'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_variant_data']['width'] . 'x' . $cart_item['custom_variant_data']['height'],
        );
    }
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'custom_get_item_data', 10, 2);


AJAX Response: {success: false, data: {…}} - and what does data actually contain? Are you seeing any of the error messages you are generating with wp_send_json_error, and if so, which one?

Post IDs in WordPress are stored as integers and since products are posts they align to this rule. I would not recommend to try and set IDs manually but just insert the product and variations into the database and let WordPress handle the IDs and it's incrementation since there is a lot more that gets IDs (media files etc). 6627db9886b28 as an ID should not be possible. Is this how the ID looks like in the posts table as well?
